# Migrating C++ code to use standard headers. Now getting: reference to 'ostream' ambiguous

Tags: c++, std, ostream

I've been migrating some code to alter the declarations of headers, since they're not included in my Ubuntu environment.  I've finally changed all of the files but have been getting the following error:

```
Item.h:33: error: reference to ‘ostream’ is ambiguous
Item.h:16: error: candidates are: struct ostream
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:130: error:                 typedef struct  
std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::ostream 
Item.h:33: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘ostream’ with no type
Item.h:33: error: ‘ostream’ is neither function nor member function; cannot be declared friend
```

Code is as follows:

```
class Item
{
public:
    Item( //const Wrd* hd,
     const Term * _term, int _start, int _finish );
    ~Item();
    int         operator== (const Item& item) const;
    friend ostream& operator<< ( ostream& os, const Item& item ); // <-- error
```

Anyone know how I would rectify this?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like in Item.h you have a line that looks like this:

```
struct ostream;
```

The problem you're getting is that `ostream` is not a `struct`; it's a `typedef` for `basic_ostream<char>`, and so your custom definition of `ostream` is conflicting with the standard definition of `ostream` that's forward-declared in `<iosfwd>`.  Consequently, when you write

```
friend ostream& operator<< ( ostream& os, const Item& item );
```

The compiler can't tell if `ostream` refers to your `struct ostream` or the more complex `typedef` exported by the standard header file.

To fix this, find the spot where you've tried to forward-declare `ostream` and remove it.  Instead, consider using the header file `<iosfwd>` to import a forward-reference to `ostream`.

More generally, you shouldn't try forward-declaring anything in the standard library.  Just `#include` the appropriate header for it.

Answer (score 1):

The comppiler tells you exactly what's going on:

there is a typedef for a template specialization ( `basic_ostream<char...>`) named `ostream` (which obviously comes from the standard header) and there is a `struct ostream` defined somewhere else in your code(which you must seek to find and rename/ramove). Hence the ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `friend std::ostream& operator<< ...`?  It is hard to answer without seeing the rest of the header.